# Disc Burner Install

Tags: burner

I am trying to install a disc burner with no luck...
This is what I have tried:

```
lena@lena:~$ sudo apt-get install brasero
[sudo] password for lena: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-5.3.0-62 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
lena@lena:~$ ^C
lena@lena:~$ ^C
lena@lena:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers 4.4.0-98
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-5.3.0-62 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
lena@lena:~$ grep -r deb/etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
lena@lena:~$ grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

etc etc
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a specific installation (Brasero) but with broken packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Make sure that you always update the list of available packages with `sudo apt update` before doing any other actions in `apt` or `apt-get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sources.list` file is not right, so you should fix that first...

```
# Fix your repsoitories
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.not_working
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/

# Add the Universe repository
sudo apt-add-repository universe

# View the contents of sources.list (original + universe repository) 
grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list

# Update if necessary
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Please note that `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list` on 18.04 LTS does not contain *universe* and *multiverse* pockets. You may need to add `sudo add-apt-repository universe ; sudo add-apt-repository multiverse` to the answer.